# Extracting part of a string based on its naming convention

Tags: python, string, extract

I'm trying to extract a piece of information about a certain file. The file name is extracted from an xml file.

The information I want is stored in the name of the file, I want to know how to extract the letters between the 2nd and 3rd period in the string.

Eg. name is extracted from the xml, it is stored as a string that looks something like this `"aa.bb.cccc.dd.ee"` and I need to find what `"cccc"` actually is in each of the strings I extract (~50 of them).

I've done some searching and some playing around with slicing etc. but I can't get even close.

I can't just specify the letter in the range `[6:11]` because the length of the string varies as does the number of characters before the part I want to find.

**UPDATE: Solution Added.**

Due to the fact the data that I was trying to split and extract part from was from an xml file it was being stored as an element.

I iterated through the list of Estate Names and stored the EstateName attribute for each one as a variable

`for element in EstateList:
         EstateStr = element.getAttribute('EstateName')`

I then used the split on this new variable which contains strings rather than elements and wrote them to the desired text file:

`asset = EstateStr.split('.', 3)[2]
 z.write(asset + "\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string on the period:

```
third_part = inputstring.split('.', 3)[2]
```

I've used [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a limit here for efficiency; no point in splitting the `dd.ee` part here, for example.

The `[2]` index then picks out the third result from the split, your `cccc` string:

```
>>> "aa.bb.cccc.dd.ee".split('.', 3)[2]
'cccc'
```

Comment: This looks like it should work perfectly. However what I thought was a string (the "aa.bb.ccc.....") is not a string, it is stored as an element because it is taken directly from an xml parse using minidom.

Comment: @JoeSmart: You mean it is one or more text nodes?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with xml or the terminology. What I know is that the file name I am working with for this is extracted from the xml using .getElementByTagName. I'm not sure if this helps you. As I said, xml is not something I'm terribly comfortable with.

Comment: @JoeSmart: so you have a DOM Element object; is the value the text value between the tags or an attribute on the tag? `<tagname>filename</tagname>` or `<tagname attrname="filename">Otherdata</tagname>`?

Comment: Much more like the second:    <estate EstateName="filename">  so theoretically it could contain otherdata, but it just doesn't at the moment.

Comment: @JoeSmart: then use `element.getAttribute('EstateName')` to get that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain it will always have this format (5 blocks of characters, separated by 4 decimals points) you can split on `'.'` then index the third element `[2]`.

```
>>> 'aa.bb.cccc.dd.ee'.split('.')[2]
'cccc'
```

This works for various string lengths so you don't have to worry about the absolute position using slicing as your first approach mentioned.

```
>>> 'a.b.c.d.e'.split('.')[2]
'c'
>>> 'eeee.ddddd.ccccc.bbbbb.aaaa'.split('.')[2]
'ccccc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use re module to extract the string between 2 and third dot.

```
>>> re.search(r'^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)\..*', "aa.bb.cccc.dd.ee").group(1)
'cccc'
```